# ZClip is not working when the click object is inside show/hide

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, primefaces, zclip

I am using ZClip and my click object is shown if a button `get_coupon_n_buy` is clicked but it is not working. It works when I have `ajax="false"` for button `get_coupon_n_buy` but if `ajax="true"` it doesnt work at all. Please find the code snippet below:

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No screen shots of code please.  Paste the actual code in here so we can read it.

Comment: Can't tell if this is relevant or not, but a number of browsers will not load Adobe Flash objects if they are initially in hidden content (zclip is an adobe flash object).  The most common work-around is to leave the zclip object as 1x1 somewhere and then position it appropriately when needed (that way it loads initiallly).